# Trying to encode a string using a given rule

Tags: java, encoding, character-encoding

I have to build an encoder/decoder tool for a particular file which contains various records and those records have multiple fields .
Now I have the description of these fields and their encoding . One particular set of encoding known as "TBCD" is as follows :

The addresses are data in TBCD format; this signifies that if one address expresses itself by the chain of numbers ‘123456789’ it appears in the following form in the ticket :

```
2 1 first byte
4 3
6 5
8 7
F 9 last byte
```

Each digit of the address is expressed in binary, on 4 bits.
The hash sign (#) is coded h’C’, Asterisk (*) is coded h’B’ and zero (0) is coded as h’0’.
The value h’F’(binary ‘1111’) serves to fill in when the number of digits of the address is odd.

For decoding this I have the following function :

```
public static String decodeTBCD(int field_size, byte[] field) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (field == null) {
        return null;
    }

    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < field_size; i++) {
            buffer.append(field[i] & 0x0F);
            if ((field[i] & 0xF0) != 0xF0)
                buffer.append((field[i] & 0xF0) >> 4);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("INFORMATION" + "  decodeTBCD   "
                + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }

    return buffer.toString();
}
```

So if the input byte array is {70,-9,1} the decoded string is 64710 .

Now I have to encode the same string back to TBCD format for this I have written the following code :

```
    Integer i = Integer.parseInt(buffer.toString());
    ArrayList<Integer> digitStack = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<StringBuilder> tbcdStack = new ArrayList<StringBuilder>();
    while (i > 0) {
        digitStack.add(i % 10);
        i = i / 10;
    }
    int j = digitStack.size();
    while (j > 0) {
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(
                Integer.toBinaryString(digitStack.get(j - 1)));
        while (s.length() != 4) {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            builder.append("0");
            builder.append(s);
            s = builder;
        }
        j--;
        System.out.println(" s : " + s + " " + s.length());
        tbcdStack.add(s);
    }
    if (tbcdStack.size() % 2 != 0)
        tbcdStack.add(new StringBuilder("1111"));
    System.out.println(tbcdStack);
    int iterator = 0, k = 0;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[tbcdStack.size() / 2];
    while (k < tbcdStack.size() / 2) {
        StringBuilder buf1 = new StringBuilder();
        buf1.append(tbcdStack.get(iterator + 1));
        buf1.append(tbcdStack.get(iterator));
        Byte b1 = Byte.valueOf(buf1.toString(), 2);
        System.out.println((byte) b1);
        bytes[k++] = b1;
        iterator += 2;
    }
```

I just reversed the process and extracted all the digits from the decoded string and then concatenating digits in the order digit2 followed by digit1 and then build a byte array with the byte{"digit2" + "digit1"} . But I donot get the correct answer with this :

```
 DECODING : inside TBCD  70,-9,1 outside TBCD  64710  
 ENCODING : input 64710 . Individual digits : 0110, 0100, 0111, 0001, 0000, 1111  

  Result : first byte = 70 (correct) , second byte = 23 (need -9) , third byte = error (11110000 out of range).
```

What am I missing here?